# Slick + Shopify theme causing strange behavior

Tags: slick.js

Live site is here: [www.wiivv.com](http://wiivv.com)
Here's a video of the issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0ckB.jpg

On mobile, buttons are skipping around when you scroll. I think the issue may have something to do with Slick Carousel.

How would you troubleshoot an issue like this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Slick is adjusting the height of your slideshow div according to the device you are using. It doesn't know to adjust the height for your second button.

The height adjustment to the div is usually done via Javascript. You can adjust the JS code to suit your buttons or put some CSS media queries in place to override what the JS is putting on your div.